# Draw shapes with random colors

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I created a program that draws 4 shapes with MousePressed Listiner. The program should draws shapes with random colors. My program draws shapes correctrly but didn't draw them with random color. Can you give me some idea how to program that.

Thanks

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Pole extends JFrame {

    public static int i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame frame= new JFrame("Shape Stamper!");

   JPanel container;
     JButton circle = new JButton("Circle");
     JButton square = new JButton("Square");
      JButton rectangle = new JButton("Rectangle");
      JButton oval = new JButton("Oval");


        container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        container.add(circle);
        container.add(square);
        container.add(rectangle);
        container.add(oval);


     circle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                i = 1;
            }
        });

     square.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                i = 2;
            }
        });

     rectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                i = 3;
            }
        });

     oval.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                i = 4;
            }
        });


     MyComponent shape = new MyComponent();
      frame.setSize(500, 500);

      frame.add(shape, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(container, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
}




import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 *
 * @author Taras
 */
public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    int i;
    Color randColor;
    public MyComponent() 
    {
        this.i = i;
        addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
    }

    private ArrayList<Rectangle2D> arrOfRect=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Ellipse2D> arrOfEllipse=new ArrayList<>();
   // private ArrayList<Color> randColor = new ArrayList<>();
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;

        g.setColor(new Color(randRed(), randGreen(), randBlue()));

        for(Rectangle2D r: arrOfRect){

            //g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);

            g2.draw(r);

        }
        for(Ellipse2D e: arrOfEllipse){

            g2.draw(e);}
      repaint();


    }
    public void add(Point2D p)
    {
        double x=p.getX();
        double y=p.getY();
        if (Pole.i == 1){
                Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100,100);
                //randColor = new Color(randRed(), randGreen(), randBlue());

                arrOfEllipse.add(ellipse);
            }
        if (Pole.i == 2){
        Rectangle2D rectangls=new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
        arrOfRect.add(rectangls);

        }
        if (Pole.i == 3){
        Rectangle2D rectangls=new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 150, 100);
        arrOfRect.add(rectangls);

        }
        if (Pole.i == 4){
                Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100,50);
                arrOfEllipse.add(ellipse);
            }
    }
    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
        {
            add(event.getPoint());
            //Color rColor = new Color(randRed(), randGreen(), randBlue());
            //randColor.add(rColor);
            randColor = new Color(randRed(), randGreen(), randBlue());

        }

    }

    private int randRed() {
        int red;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        red = randomNumber.nextInt(255);
        return red;
    }

    private int randGreen() {
        int green;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        green = randomNumber.nextInt(255);
        return green;
    }

    private int randBlue() {
        int blue;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        blue = randomNumber.nextInt(255);
        return blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem in next you set `Color` only once for all components here:

```
g.setColor(new Color(randRed(), randGreen(), randBlue()));
```

but if you want to change color for each shape you need to call `setColor()` each time.

You can use one instance of `Random` change your `paintComponent()` method like next and your shapes will have different colors :

```
Random rand = new Random();
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (Rectangle2D r : arrOfRect) {
        g.setColor(new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat()));
        g2.draw(r);

    }
    for (Ellipse2D e : arrOfEllipse) {
        g.setColor(new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat()));
        g2.draw(e);
    }

}
```

Also it's wrong to call `repaint()` inside `paintComponent()` method, remove that line and repaint your panel after adding new shape, for example:

```
private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        add(event.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is to paint every shape with a random color then you'd have to update `graphics` color for every shape that is drawn. Ie:

```
for (Rectangle2D r : arrOfRect) {
    g.setColor(getRandomColor());
    g2.draw(r);
}
```

There is no need to allocate new `Random` in every call, you can make it a private member. For example:

```
private Random randomNumber = new Random();

private Color getRandomColor() {
    return new Color(randomNumber.nextFloat(),
            randomNumber.nextFloat(), randomNumber.nextFloat());
}
```

If you want to assign a random color to each shape in `add()` method and keep it then you'd have to maintain a map of colors, or some other structure that serves the goal.

Other minor but important notes:

- Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()` inside your implementation of `paintComponent`.
- Do not call `repaint()` in `paintComponent()`, as it eventually triggers `paintComponent`. So you're creating unnecessary repaints.
- Do call `repaint()` inside `add()` to repaint the component with a newly created shape.

  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details and examples.